# Delete subfolders and files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file-io, delete-directory

Is it possible to delete all the subfolders (with content) and files within a folder?

For example:

- Backup

  - November

    - pic1.jpg
    - pic2.jpg
  - December
  - January

    - pic3.jpg
  - example1.txt
  - example2.txt
  - example3.txt

There is a root folder (Backup). This root folder contains 3 subfolders (with content) and 3 text files. How can I delete the whole content (3 subfolders and 3 files) of the Backup folder without deleting the root folder (Backup) itself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx) class has a **Delete** method that accepts a parameter that forces the deleting operation recursively on the folder passed

```
' Loop over the subdirectories and remove them with their contents
For Each d in Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Backup")
    Directory.Delete(d, true)
Next

' Finish removing also the files in the root folder
For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("c:\backup") 
     File.Delete(f) 
Next
```

**FROM MSDN Directory.Delete**

> Deletes the specified directory and, if indicated, any subdirectories
>   and files in the directory.

Comment: Also, For Each DirectoryFile As String In Directory.GetFiles("c:\backup") File.Delete(DirectoryFile) Next to delete the files as well.