# How to delete all files inside %temp% directory ? VB

Tags: vb.net

I am creating cleaner I want to clean all files in %temp% directory but I can't find the solution to do so

Here is my current code but it's not working I don't know why.
When I click on button nothing happens and I am running my program in admin mode.

```
    Dim tempclean As Thread
    Dim tempfolderpath As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath

    Public Sub tempcleaning()
        For Each filepath In Directory.GetFiles(tempfolderpath)
            Try
                File.Delete(filepath)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub
```

Button Code

```
            tempclean = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf tempsmetlar)
            tempclean.Start()
```

Comment: The empty Catch is swallowing any errors. Get rid of the Try...Catch...End Try temporarily to see what errors you are getting.

Comment: 1) Why are you deleting files on a seperate thread? (2) Shouldn't `New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf tempsmetlar)` be `New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf tempcleaning)`?

Comment: It's working now but it only deletes files and not folder I want to delete all in temp

Comment: to delete all folders and files in a directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27273012/2264365